# PHP: Extract specific word after specific word in a string?

Tags: php

I have a string that looks like this:

```
{"ip":"XX.XX.XX","country_code":"IE","country_name":"Ireland","region_code":"L","region_name":"Leinster","city":"Dublin","zip_code":"","time_zone":"Europe/Dublin","latitude":53.333,"longitude":-6.249,"metro_code":0}
```

i only need the value for the `country_name` from that string.

so I tried this:

```
$country = '{"ip":"XX.XX.XX","country_code":"IE","country_name":"Ireland","region_code":"L","region_name":"Leinster","city":"Dublin","zip_code":"","time_zone":"Europe/Dublin","latitude":53.333,"longitude":-6.249,"metro_code":0}';

if (preg_match('#^country_name: ([^\s]+)#m', $country, $match)) {
    $result = $match[1];
}

echo $result;
```

but there is nothing being echoed in the `$result`

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: this looks like a json string. you should find a library that can convert it to an object and extract the value from that object. This is way easier than string parsing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$country = json_decode('{"ip":"XX.XX.XX","country_code":"IE","country_name":"Ireland","region_code":"L","region_name":"Leinster","city":"Dublin","zip_code":"","time_zone":"Europe/Dublin","latitude":53.333,"longitude":-6.249,"metro_code":0}');

echo $country->country_name;
```

What you have there is a JSON string.

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation.
PHP can decode it into an Array or Object via json_decode($string, FALSE);

The 2nd parameter by default is FALSE, which means it will convert the string into an object, which you can then access as I showed you above.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you don't want to use JSON you can give the following a try. Note that using JSON is the recommended way doing this task.

```
$country = '{"ip":"XX.XX.XX","country_code":"IE","country_name":"Ireland","region_code":"L","region_name":"Leinster","city":"Dublin","zip_code":"","time_zone":"Europe/Dublin","latitude":53.333,"longitude":-6.249,"metro_code":0}';

$temp = explode('"country_name":', $country); //Explode initial string
$temp_country = explode(',', $temp[1]); //Get only country name
$country_name = str_replace('"', ' ', $temp_country[0]); //Remove double quotes
echo $country_name;
```

Result:

```
Ireland
```

Comment: In my honest opinion, when you have a JSON string, you shouldn't even think about treating it as a regular string and use explodes and such. Hence the downvote.

Comment: This is why i didn't just write down the code but i first had the phrase: " If for some reason you don't want to use JSON " !

Comment: I also upvoted the accepted answer because it was a good answer but it's nice to provide other options too (just in case).

Comment: Alright. Edit the answer so I can remove my downvote.

Comment: I think it looks better now giving that note.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$country=json_decode('{"ip":"XX.XX.XX","country_code":"IE","country_name":"Ireland","region_code":"L","region_name":"Leinster","city":"Dublin","zip_code":"","time_zone":"Europe/Dublin","latitude":53.333,"longitude":-6.249,"metro_code":0}')
$result=$country->country_name;
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Works, but why the `{}`?  Not needed here.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I tried to implement as demonstrated in the Manual. Check it out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: That's for **invalid** property names, `country_name` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Uh... You don't want the quotes either :-(

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a json string. Read more about [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

Use it like this:

```
$foo = '{"ip":"XX.XX.XX","country_code":"IE","country_name":"Ireland","region_code":"L","region_name":"Leinster","city":"Dublin","zip_code":"","time_zone":"Europe/Dublin","latitude":53.333,"longitude":-6.249,"metro_code":0}';
$bar = json_decode($foo, true);
echo $bar['country_name'];
```

This can be used with any `key` from that string (eg `ip`, `city`)

More about [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: a`